# Creating signed request for S3 upload using Django

Tags: javascript, python, django, amazon-web-services, amazon-s3

I have a simple django app on heroku for uploading images and it works as expected when accessed from desktop but fails to sign the requests for upload to AWS S3 when I access the site on mobile.

The signing code is shown below:

```
def sign_s3(request):
    request = request.GET
    S3_BUCKET = os.environ.get('AWS_STORAGE_BUCKET_NAME')

    file_name = request.get('file_name')
    file_type = request.get('file_type')

    s3 = boto3.client('s3')

    presigned_post = s3.generate_presigned_post(
    Bucket = S3_BUCKET,
    Key = file_name,
    Fields = {"acl": "public-read", "Content-Type": file_type},
    Conditions = [
        {"acl": "public-read"},
        {"Content-Type": file_type}
    ],
    ExpiresIn = 3600
    )

    return HttpResponse(json.dumps({
    'data': presigned_post,
    'url': 'https://%s.s3.amazonaws.com/%s' % (S3_BUCKET, file_name)
    }))
```

I set everything in the S3 bucket to public and have the CORS set as

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<CORSConfiguration xmlns="http://s3.amazonaws.com/doc/2006-03-01/">
<CORSRule>
    <AllowedOrigin>*</AllowedOrigin>
    <AllowedMethod>GET</AllowedMethod>
    <AllowedMethod>POST</AllowedMethod>
    <AllowedMethod>PUT</AllowedMethod>
    <AllowedHeader>*</AllowedHeader>
</CORSRule>
</CORSConfiguration>
```

This is a sample of the javascript used to send the request. I have realised it doesnt seem to send at all when its on mobile. The status code comes out as 0.

```
function getSignedRequest(file){
  var xhr = new XMLHttpRequest();
  xhr.open("GET", "/sign_s3?file_name="+file.name+"&file_type="+file.type);
  xhr.onreadystatechange = function(){
    if(xhr.readyState === 4){
      if(xhr.status === 200){
        var response = JSON.parse(xhr.responseText);
        uploadFile(file, response.data, response.url);
      }
      else{
        alert("Could not get signed URL.");
      }
    }
  };
  xhr.send();
}
```

`uploadFile` is just a separate function that finally posts the image.

I cant tell what could be causing this difference. How can I get this working?

Comment: whats the purpose of `'url': 'https://%s.s3.amazonaws.com/%s' % (S3_BUCKET, file_name)` parameter

Comment: @ArunK its the url where the image will be posted to by the javascript on client side

Comment: the idea of pre-signed url is to generate an url with a signature embedded to give you temporary access. the presigned url will be inside the data object. you are suppose to be using the presigned url instead of `the url `https://bucket-name.s3.amazonaws.com/filename.jpg`.  am i missing something

Comment: @ArunK Thats correct. `presigned_post` is a dictionary with the signature and everything needed to upload. You'll still have to create the url string to upload to. That can be done in client side too since that info is inside `presigned_post` but I chose to just do it in backend.

Comment: I get it now. thank you.

Comment: Sure no worries

Comment: So the presigned URLs are always generated. But when you upload the file using the generated presigned url from the mobile it's not working?

Comment: @ArunK They always generated as expected when I upload from a computer.

Answer (score 0):

Instead of:

```xml
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<CORSConfiguration xmlns="http://s3.amazonaws.com/doc/2006-03-01/">
<CORSRule>
    <AllowedOrigin>*</AllowedOrigin>
    <AllowedMethod>GET</AllowedMethod>
    <AllowedMethod>POST</AllowedMethod>
    <AllowedMethod>PUT</AllowedMethod>
    <AllowedHeader>*</AllowedHeader>
</CORSRule>
</CORSConfiguration>
```

try adding the CORSRules this way:

```xml
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<CORSConfiguration xmlns="http://s3.amazonaws.com/doc/2006-03-01/">
<CORSRule>
    <AllowedOrigin>*</AllowedOrigin>
    <AllowedMethod>GET</AllowedMethod>
    <AllowedHeader>*</AllowedHeader>
</CORSRule>
<CORSRule>
    <AllowedOrigin>*</AllowedOrigin>
    <AllowedMethod>POST</AllowedMethod>
    <AllowedHeader>*</AllowedHeader>
</CORSRule>
...
</CORSConfiguration>
```

Comment: I've added some javascript that I'm using. The request has a status code of 0 so seems its not even getting to backend

Answer (score 0):

Just found out the issue is with the XMLHttpRequest object which doesn't seem to work well /unsupported on iPhone if async is set to true which is the default value, not sure on android.

I changed to
 `xhr.open("GET", "/sign_s3?file_name="+file.name+"&file_type="+file.type, false);` and everything works.
This makes the request synchronous so seems asynchronous requests are being blocked by ios.

When doing the actual upload, having the async set to false means its not possible to track the progress.

Again, async set to false is not allowed in Firefox, what a pain. Until I find a better solution, I'll have to implement different code for Firefox and mobile browsers by detecting the type of browser being used.